# Can't install different android app version in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing an app in Android Studio which I've installed previously on a simulator. Now I want to simultaneously run an older version of same app on SAME sim. So I loaded up the corresponding older code in another Android Studio instance and refactored the project with different package name but when I go to install the older code I get the message

> Installation failed since the device already has a newer
>   version of this application...

I assumed that renaming the package would make it a different app from point of view of Android OS... What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably refactored the Java package. The Java code structure isn't what Android checks.

Open your app's `build.gradle` and change the `applicationId` field.

Comment: this does not provide a dynamic solution, but requires changing it for each duplicate install.

Comment: Bingo! This is all I needed and addresses my exact question. Thanks

Comment: @MartinZeitler why is that needed? It answers the question, and it doesn't sound like OP is planning on having more than 2 versions installed at once.

Comment: @TheWanderer `applicationIdSuffix ".legacy"` might have been rather elegant... while I'd already wonder about the idea of testing old versions - unless it works fine - opposite to the newer version (for direct comparison, while rebuilding).